# how to use protobuf.any in golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm using grpc in my go project. Below is code:

example.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Example {
    string message = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any details = 2;
}
```

main.go

```
func logMessage (m string, d interface{}) {
    message := & example.message{
       message: m,
       details: ??
    }    
    log(&message)
}
```

But I'm not sure how to deal with the details(interface{}) field. I know I can use any type for interface, but not sure how to use it here. Anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [protobuf/ptypes](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes) package has utilities to convert to/from arbitrary proto messages to any:

---

[MarshalAny](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#MarshalAny):

`func MarshalAny(m proto.Message) (*anypb.Any, error)`

MarshalAny marshals the given message m into an anypb.Any message.

---

[UnmarshalAny](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#UnmarshalAny):

`func UnmarshalAny(any *anypb.Any, m proto.Message) error`

UnmarshalAny unmarshals the encoded value contained in the anypb.Any message into the provided message m. It returns an error if the target message does not match the type in the Any message or if an unmarshal error occurs.

---

In your example, you would use something along the lines of:

```golang
func logMessage (m string, d proto.Message) {
    details, err := ptypes.MarshalAny(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    message := & example.message{
        message: m,
        details: details
    }    
    log(&message)
}
```

Comment: but currently, `d` is just an `interface{}` instead of `proto.Message`. Is that mean I need to make it a proto message first? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Ultimately, `protobuf.Any` **has to be a proto.Message**. You can either pass one directly, or do a type assertion. eg: `d.(proto.Message)`

Comment: **Deprecated**: Call the [any.UnmarshalTo](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb#Any.UnmarshalTo) method instead.

Answer (score 13):

Since protobuf/ptypes is deprecated, it worth using [`anypb.UnmarshalTo`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb#hdr-Unmarshaling_an_Any)

```golang
import (
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb"
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any"
)

func Unmarshal(data *any.Any) (*YourMessage, err) {
    var m YourMessage
    err := anypb.UnmarshalTo(data, &m, proto.UnmarshalOptions{})
    return &m,err
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func pbany(v interface{}) (*anypb.Any, error) {
pv, ok := v.(proto.Message)
if !ok {
    return &anypb.Any{}, fmt.Errorf("%v is not proto.Message", pv)
}
return anypb.New(pv)
```

use `anypb.New` api, In your code, pass `d` to pbany function

Answer (score -1):

```
func interfaceToAny(v interface{}) (*anypb.Any, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        println("error json.Marshal interfaceToAny")
        return nil, err
    }
    m := api.Bytes{B: bytes}
    return anypb.New(&m)
}

message Bytes {
  bytes b = 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func ConvertInterfaceToAny(v interface{}) (*any.Any, error) {
 anyValue := &any.Any{}
 bytes, _ := json.Marshal(v)
 bytesValue := &wrappers.BytesValue{
    Value: bytes,
 }
 err := anypb.MarshalFrom(anyValue, bytesValue, proto.MarshalOptions{})
 return anyValue, err
```

}